# getting data from entire-x web service writing xml language on the query designer in ssrs

Tags: xml, web-services

i'm using web service on data source xml connection.
when entring the link of web service i'm getting the schema and not the data.
how can i get the data with the write synax on the query designer.
the web service suppose to have method to get parameters and then to give output list of fields with data.
i tried for now to write the query like this:

```
<Query>
</Query>
```

that just gave the fields name
or

```
<Query>
<SoapAction>addresslocation</SoapAction>
<Mathod Name=serviceroutinename namespace=addresslocation>
<Parameters>
<Paramenter Name=field>

</Parameter>
</Parameters>
</Method>
<Query>
```

but i got error on the endpoint

Answer (score 0):

my namespace was incorrect and this is why i got an error, after changing to the correct namespace it was ok

Answer (score 0):

I have still issues retrieving the data via the reporting services visual studio. I'm sending the soapaction,method,namespace and parameters and from reason from the server side the dba said that the input parameters are reaching as 0.so when I'm getting answer from the web service the output parameters are all 0.there are 2 issues im suspecting. I saw an article saying that ssrs are adding Bom parsing and the Java based ws cannot read it,another option is the soapaction even that I took it from the ws scheme so I don't see there is a problem but maybe I'm wrong,any assistance?